# How was the index replace?

Tags: summation

[image]

This is page from The Art of Computer Programming by D.E.Knuth.
I am interested in circled and underlined

Why he is just change $n-j$ on $j$ ?

Comment: $0 \leq n-j \iff j \leq n$, $n-j \leq n \iff j \geq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no change of index, the limits have been simply rewritten: the inequality $0\leq n-j$ is equivalent to $j\leq n$ and the inequality $n-j\leq n$ is equivalent to $0\leq j$. In other words
$$0\leq n-j\leq n\quad \Leftrightarrow\quad 0\leq j\leq n.$$

Comment: Thank your very much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the referred paragraph:

[image]

**First**, there was a change of index according to the rule $(b)$.

If you consider $i=p(j)=n-j$, then:
$$\sum_{0\le i\le n} (a+bi)=\sum_{0\le j\le n} (a+bj)=\sum_{0\le n-j\le n} (a+b(n-j)).$$

**Second**, the index was simplified:
$$0\le n-j\le n \stackrel{\times (-1)}\iff \\
0\ge j-n\ge -n \iff \\
-n\le j-n\le 0 \stackrel{+n}\iff\\
0\le j\le n.  $$